# Run procedure when forever button stops?

Tags: netlogo

I would like to run a procedure whenever the the user unclicks a forever button.

Specifically, I'm using a forever button to allow the user to select a set of turtles (using methods from Code Examples in the Models Library).  Once the set is selected, I want to write statistics calculated for the set to an Output window.  (I can display this information from inside the button procedure, but then it updates continually, which is ugly.)  A monitor element would do what I want display of a single number, but I want to be able to display an arbitrary number of values--one for each subset of the selected set of turtles.  At present, I have a separate button that causes the statistics to be displayed, but I'd rather make it happen automatically.

If it's not possible to run a procedure on exist from a forever'ed procedure, is there another solution that you would suggest?

Thanks!

Comment: You might also consider adding in another function to your button that's called if a certain number of ticks is exceeded, but ignored if not. For example, your 'Go' (forever) button could be used to call the function Go as well as: if ticks >= X [Calculate_statistics].  That way every time the button is pushed it will run the if statement, but only do your stats if the model has been run longer than X

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NetLogo has no "on exit" procedures, nor anything similar.

Given this limitation, the way I would approach your problem would be to keep the display of statistics at the end of your "forever" procedure, but to only display them if they need updating (i.e., if anything has changed). If you call `clear-output` before each update, you can achieve something that looks a lot like a "multi-line monitor".